# Finding recessions in US GDP data using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, homework, pandas

For an assignment, I am identifying the first quarter of the 2008 recession in the United States. The Excel data I'm using can be downloaded here: [gdplev.xls](https://github.com/lytemar/Introduction-to-Data-Science-in-Python--University-of-Michigan---Coursera/blob/master/gdplev.xls). How can I improve this pandas code to make it more idiomatic or optimized?

```
def get_recession_start():
    '''Returns the year and quarter of the recession start time as a 
    string value in a format such as 2005q3'''
    GDP_df = pd.read_excel("gdplev.xls", 
                           names=["Quarter", "GDP in 2009 dollars"], 
                           parse_cols = "E,G", 
                           skiprows = 7)
    GDP_df = GDP_df.query("Quarter >= '2000q1'")
    GDP_df["Growth"] = GDP_df["GDP in 2009 dollars"].pct_change()
    GDP_df = GDP_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    # recession defined as two consecutive quarters of negative growth
    GDP_df["Recession"] = (GDP_df.Growth < 0) & (GDP_df.Growth.shift(-1) < 0) 
    return GDP_df.iloc[GDP_df["Recession"].idxmax()]["Quarter"]
get_recession_start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function does too many things: reading Excel file, filtering necessary rows, and calculating the "recession_start". My advice is to take the first two out.

Also, supply quarters and GDP as separate objects (`pd.Series`) to the function instead of the DataFrame. Like this you will remove hardcoded strings from your function, and, what's more important, you will get rid of `SettingWithCopyWarning` that you should get right now:

```
df = pd.read_excel('gdplev.xls',
                   names=['Quarter', 'GDP in 2009 dollars'],
                   usecols='E,G',
                   skiprows=7)
mask = df['Quarter'] >= '2000q1'
print(get_recession_start(quarters=df.loc[mask, 'Quarter'],
                          gdps=df.loc[mask, 'GDP in 2009 dollars']))
```

Note that I use `usecols` instead of `parse_cols` as it is deprecated. Also, I removed `df.query` in favor of boolean masking and `.loc`.

Then, the function would look like this:

```
def get_recession_start(quarters: pd.Series,
                        gdps: pd.Series) -> str:
    """
    Returns the year and quarter of the recession start time
    as a string value in a format such as 2005q3
    """
    growth = gdps.pct_change()
    recession = (growth < 0) & (growth.shift(-1) < 0)
    recession = recession.reset_index(drop=True)
    return quarters.iloc[recession.idxmax()]
```

Here I also used [triple double quotes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes) for the docstring and [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). IMHO, this looks much cleaner.

Probably, it would also make sense to return only the `recession.idxmax()` index and get corresponding `quarters` value outside of the function.